# BigQuery group by specific age ranges and sex

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with age and sex fields, and I can group by like so:

```
bq query --max_rows=9999 --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, age, sex FROM `project.dataset.table` GROUP BY age, sex ORDER BY age, sex' 2>/dev/null | head -n 11 | csvtk pretty 
COUNT   age    sex
143     50.0   Female
77      50.0   Male
28      51.0   Female
78      51.0   Male
30      52.0   Female
22      52.0   Male
79      53.0   Female
81      53.0   Male
111     54.0   Female
[...]
```

I would like to group by specific age ranges: 50-59, 60-69, 60-79 and 80 or older.

How do I turn the query above so that I can group by the specific age ranges?

Also, a slight complication is that my `sex` field can be `F, Female` or `M, Male`. How do I lump the two types into one when grouping?

EDIT: I was thinking that the output could look like this:

```
COUNT,agegroup,sex
10,50-59,Female
[...]
```

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN age >= 50 and age < 60 then '50-59'
             WHEN age < 70 then '60-69'
             WHEN age < 80 THEN '70-79'
             WHEN age >= 80 THEN '80+'
        END) as agegrp, sex,
       COUNT(*) as nt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY agegrp, sex
ORDER BY sex, MIN(age);
```

If you need to group by `F, Female` and `M, Male` and you need to cast age as FLOAT64, the full answer would be:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN CAST(age AS FLOAT64) >= 50 and CAST(age AS FLOAT64) < 60 then "50-59"
             WHEN CAST(age AS FLOAT64) < 70 then "60-60" 
             WHEN CAST(age AS FLOAT64) < 80 THEN "70-79" 
             WHEN CAST(age AS FLOAT64) >= 80 THEN "80+" END) as agegrp,
        (CASE WHEN sex IN ("F","Female") then "F" 
              WHEN sex IN ("M","Male") then "M" END) AS sexgrp,
       COUNT(*) as nt 
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
GROUP BY agegrp, sexgrp ORDER BY sexgrp, MIN(CAST(age AS FLOAT64))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a more generic way by, say, providing a bin size of 10 with a lower and upper limit? Using a `CASE` with a more granular requirement (say age buckets of 2 years) would make the query unnecessarily large.

Comment: @IM94 . . . Yes, but that should be asked as a *new* question not as a comment.